# Laravel eloquent return 0 if the value for update is the same as the previous data in the database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem in laravel 8, when I run the query below for the first time it works without any problems, but when I rerun it, it always shows a failure message unless I change the "isprocess" value to be different from before for the update.

How can I continue to display a success message even though the updated value remains the same?

```
$updateIsProses = DB::table('pricelist_naikharga')->whereDate('tanggal', '<=', '2022-05-01')->update(["isproses" => 1]);

       if($updateIsProses){
            echo outputJson(200, "BerhasilSuccess");
       }else{
            echo outputJson(500, "Fail");
       }
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL? If new values are same as old ones, MySQL does not update the row although query executes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The `update()` method from the query builder returns the number of affected rows.

Checking that value for fail or success is inaccurate since running twice the same query will have the second one affecting no row, hence returning 0 which is evaluated as `false`

If an error occurs, an exception will be thrown

```
try {
    $updatedRowCount = DB::table('pricelist_naikharga')->whereDate('tanggal', '<=', '2022-05-01')->update(["isproses" => 1]);
catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo outputJson(500, "Fail");
}

echo outputJson(200, "BerhasilSuccess, affected Rows: ".$updatedRowCount);
```